# Incompatible types: List<FollowUser> cannot be converted to ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Am trying to pass a `List<>` from an activity to a fragment.

When an imageView is clicked; the onClick event triggers a call to the server that takes the userId of the user that clicked on the imageView and the userId of the users profile you want to see.i have an interface that  that takes the response gotten from the server, which is then sent to a new fragment class. The problem am having is that i cannot pass a `List<>` through the bundle.

This is the `newInstance` of the fragment class and the parameter am trying to send across

```
  public static HomeUserProfileFragment newInstance(String postTotal, String followersTotal
        , String followingTotal, List<UploadPost> uploadPostList, List<FollowUser> followersList, List<FollowUser> followingList) {

    HomeUserProfileFragment fragment = new HomeUserProfileFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(POST_TOTAL, postTotal);
    args.putString(FOLLOWERS_TOTAL, followersTotal);
    args.putString(FOLLOWING_TOTAL, followingTotal);
    args.putStringArrayList(UPLOAD_POST_LIST,uploadPostList);
    args.putStringArrayList(FOLLOWERS_LIST,followersList);
    args.putStringArrayList(FOLLOWING_LIST, followingList);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

While this is the the Activity class that the Above Fragment is been called from.

```
 @Override
public void onClickUserProfile(String post, String followers, String following, List<UploadPost> uploadPostList, List<FollowUser> followersList, List<FollowUser> followingList) {

    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container,   HomeUserProfileFragment.newInstance(post, followers, following,uploadPostList,followersList,followingList))
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

So am getting the following errors:

```
Error:(56, 50) error: incompatible types: List<UploadPost> cannot be converted to ArrayList<String>
Error:(57, 48) error: incompatible types: List<FollowUser> cannot be converted to ArrayList<String>
Error:(58, 49) error: incompatible types: List<FollowUser> cannot be converted to ArrayList<String>
```

Comment: `args.putStringArrayList` doesn't work with a list that is not a **StringArrayList**

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Bundle args= new Bundle();  
args.putParcelableArrayList(POST_TOTAL, postTotal);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

instead of

```
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putString(POST_TOTAL, postTotal);
 fragment.setArguments(args);
```

After this you can get back this data by using

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  
ArrayList<ObjectName> arraylist  = extras.getParcelableArrayList("arraylist");
```

Comment: The problem seems not to be about the `String` value *postTotal*, so your (basically correct) approach may be misunderstood. One should also mention that OP has to have each of the problem classes [implement Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have `List`s which are not `ArrayList`s.

A solution might be to wrap your list into an `ArrayList` with one of its constructors:

```
args.putStringArrayList(UPLOAD_POST_LIST, new ArrayList<>(uploadPostList));
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a solution. I had to implement Parcelable to UploadPost model class and FollowUser model class. Since these two model class are called in a third class that hold them as well as other parameters that are sent from the server, i had to implement Parcelable to the model class.

Then: newInstance method of Fragment class:

```
 public static HomeUserProfileFragment newInstance(String yourId, String other_UserId,  String name,String username,String userImage,String postTotal, String followersTotal
        , String followingTotal, ArrayList<UploadPost> uploadPostList, ArrayList<FollowUser> followersList, ArrayList<FollowUser> followingList) {

    HomeUserProfileFragment fragment = new HomeUserProfileFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(YOUR_USER_ID, yourId); // this holds the id of the user that his profile wants to be seen.
    args.putString(VIEWER_USER_ID, other_UserId); // this holds the id of the user that want to see your profile. this Id is used to determine if the user is a friend or not.so if not a friend the follow button will be displayed.
    args.putString(NAME,name);
    args.putString(USERNAME, username);
    args.putString(USER_IMAGE, userImage);
    args.putString(POST_TOTAL, postTotal);
    args.putString(FOLLOWERS_TOTAL, followersTotal);
    args.putString(FOLLOWING_TOTAL, followingTotal);
    args.putParcelableArrayList(UPLOAD_POST_LIST,  uploadPostList);
    args.putParcelableArrayList(FOLLOWERS_LIST,  followersList);
    args.putParcelableArrayList(FOLLOWING_LIST,  followingList);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

And Activity class calling Fragment:

```
    @Override
public void onClickUserProfile(String yourId, String viewerId, String name, String username, String userImage, String post,
                               String followers, String following, ArrayList<UploadPost> uploadPostList, ArrayList<FollowUser> followersList, ArrayList<FollowUser> followingList) {
    this.yourId = yourId;
    this.viewerId = viewerId;
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container,   HomeUserProfileFragment.newInstance(yourId,viewerId,name, username,userImage,post, followers, following,uploadPostList,followersList,followingList))
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

that is my Answer