# NullPointerException when sending nested ArrayList via Parcelable

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable

I am trying to send a nested ArrayList object via Parcelable intent. Name of custom object is 'ExampleItem' which contains nested custom object 'B'. I am sending from MainActivity to Activity2. I get NullPointerException error *"Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference"*. How do i succesfully send via Parcelable?

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    private ArrayList<B> mBList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void Press(View view) {

        B b = new B("hello");
        mBList = new ArrayList<>();
        mBList.add(b);

        mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "Line 1", "Line 2", mBList));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "Line 3", "Line 4", mBList));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "Line 5", "Line 6", mBList));

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Example Item", mExampleList);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Activity2

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
    
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleItem = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("Example Item");
    
        }
    }
```

ExampleItem

```
public class ExampleItem implements Parcelable {
    private int mImageResource;
    private String mText1;
    private String mText2;
    private ArrayList<B> mList;


    public ExampleItem(int imageResource, String text1, String text2, ArrayList<B> list) {
        mImageResource = imageResource;
        mText1 = text1;
        mText2 = text2;
        mList = list;
    }

    protected ExampleItem(Parcel in) {
        mImageResource = in.readInt();
        mText1 = in.readString();
        mText2 = in.readString();
        in.readList(mList, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Creator<ExampleItem> CREATOR = new Creator<ExampleItem>() {
        @Override
        public ExampleItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ExampleItem(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ExampleItem[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ExampleItem[size];
        }
    };

    public int getImageResource() {
        return mImageResource;
    }

    public String getText1() {
        return mText1;
    }

    public String getText2() {
        return mText2;
    }

    public ArrayList<B> getmList() {
        return mList;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(mImageResource);
        dest.writeString(mText1);
        dest.writeString(mText2);
        dest.writeList(mList);
    }

}
```

B

```
public class B implements Parcelable {

    public String str;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }


    public B(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    private B(Parcel in) {
        str = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<B> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<B>() {
        public B createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new B(in);
        }

        public B[] newArray(int size) {
            return new B[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(str);
    }

}
```

Output Log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.codinginflow.exampleparcelable, PID: 9376
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.codinginflow.exampleparcelable/com.codinginflow.exampleparcelable.Activity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:3632)
        at android.os.Parcel.readList(Parcel.java:2559)
        at com.codinginflow.exampleparcelable.ExampleItem.<init>(ExampleItem.java:26)
        at com.codinginflow.exampleparcelable.ExampleItem$1.createFromParcel(ExampleItem.java:32)
        at com.codinginflow.exampleparcelable.ExampleItem$1.createFromParcel(ExampleItem.java:29)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:3281)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:3174)
        at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:3630)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:2758)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:3195)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3567)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:292)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:236)
        at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1001)
        at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:8276)
        at com.codinginflow.exampleparcelable.Activity2.onCreate(Activity2.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove white spaces from **Example Item** You Should pass data like this

**Add Data**

```
ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "Line 1", "Line 2", mBList));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "Line 3", "Line 4", mBList));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "Line 5", "Line 6", mBList));
```

**Send Data**

first, create a bundle and put your items there then pass the bundle to your intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FromActivity.this, ToActivity.class); 
Bundle bundle;
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("example_item", items); 
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

**Get Data**

```
 ArrayList<ExampleItem> items= intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("example_item");
```

**EDIT**

> In my opinion you should Use JsonParsing and then send your data with StringExtra.

You should implement your pojo item with **`parcelable`**

look at this example [how to pass Array list <Object> to another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303371/how-to-pass-array-list-object-to-another-activity/45303432)

Comment: i still receive the following error message: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.Bundle.putParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference"